# On the Jeeves and Wooster TV show does Wooster say “Don’t you know?” much like the character does in the P.G. Wodehouse books?

Tags: character, jeeves-and-wooster

In the British *Jeeves and Wooster* ITV TV series (1990-1993) with Hugh Laurie and Stephen Fry, does Wooster ever—or indeed frequently—say “Don’t you know?”, like he frequently does in the books? For example, “He’s my butler, don’t you know?”

The line is one of the most endearing things about Wooster and is quite important to some people who like authenticity. I watched the first two episodes but alas I heard no trace of this line.

Also, a Google search reveals only two episodes where it is employed.

Comment: Why the four downvotes?

Comment: Personally, lack of research. - If you're unwilling to watch even a short part of a TV episode to find out your answer, why should we? I haven't read the books but it seems sort of silly to refuse to watch what was a very successful show simply because there may not be a specific tag line in it.

Comment: @Catija But I did do research: I watched the first two episodes (2 hours). Also it's not like I'm asking people to watch the full series and tell me the answer. Obviously, there exist people who have watched the full series who therefore already know the answer, and it would be of no hassle to them to answer me.

Comment: And regarding your last sentence, that tag line is one of the endearing things about Wooster, and is quite essential to the book for many people.

Comment: How are we supposed to know this? You don't mention it in the question. The way you've written the question seems like it's below you to bother watching the show if it doesn't do that one thing. If you **have** watched two episodes, mention the fact in the question and explain why you think this one line is so important.

Comment: @Catija Agreed. But my point in my last sentence of my first comment to you still stands.

Comment: Of course there are other people who have seen the show... but, seeing the response so far, it doesn't seem that there are a ton of them here... I'm not saying you *won't* get an answer... and I didn't say that you shouldn't get one... I just said that, personally, I don't think this is a good question, and I'm allowed to think that.

Comment: Thanks for your additions, the question has quite a bit more substance with them.

Comment: I did start looking, but frankly don't have the time - You can search through all the episode transcripts here: http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/episode_scripts.php?tv-show=jeeves-and-wooster

Comment: Jeeves was Woosters valet, not his butler.

Answer (score 4):

**Yes**, in the episode *'Cyril and the Broadway Musical'*

> *[Oh, l don't know, don't you know?](http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=jeeves-and-wooster&episode=s03e03)*

---

He also comes close by saying, *'Dont' you think?'* several times:

> *[And her handicap's only six! lt's funny how these things turn out, don't you think, Jeeves?](http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=jeeves-and-wooster&episode=s01e01)* - Season 1, episode 1
>
> *[Got a sort of ring to it, don't you think?](http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=jeeves-and-wooster&episode=s01e03)* - Season 1, episode 3
>
> *[Ocean Breeze looks the part, don't you think, Jeeves?](http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=jeeves-and-wooster&episode=s03e06)* - Season 3, episode 6